# Bootstrap 3 nested col doesn't take parent style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why a nested col doesn't take the style of parent div ? Here is an example where the background should be blue :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="background-color: blue;">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To make it work, we have to specify a height to the parent div, but I want the height of my div has the same height of my col responsively.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the "Collapsing Parent" or "Great Collapse" issue, you can get a pretty good idea about it here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Basically, if this parent element contains nothing but floated elements, it's height would collapse to nothing.

Since you're using bootstrap you could use the `clearfix` class which already comes within it and apply it to that parent div, like this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="clearfix" style="background-color: blue;">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info about clearfix checkout bootstrap's documentation on this matter here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-clearfix

Comment: I think that it's the most appropriate answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in fact the background is blue but you can't see it because the padding of the div is 0px.
you can add for example: padding: 0px;

Answer (score 0):

The col has a float:left CSS property so the parent should have a floating property set (left or right) to actually contain the child element.

Two options:

1-) set the parent to float: left;

2-) Make the parent display as flex, then it will force the child element to be inside of it.

Comment: Thank you it works but I think that a clearfix is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different approach to solve this 
1) Just add that background color inline style on the "". 
2) Make your background color div floated.

As your parent row div is floated element you should add any style with floated element.

like `<div class="row" style="background-color: blue"><div class="col-xs-12">....</div></div>`.

Hope this can help you.